# Why are Angular changes not being reflected in browser after build?

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome

I have an angular project and sometimes when I make changes, they are not reflected in the browser.  I am using chrome and have cleared the cache pages and cookies.  I also have *disable cache* checked in the *network* tab of developer tools.

I have also cleared the angular cache using *ng build --prod --aot --outputHashing=all*.  After doing that their are tons of errors which are cleared up after doing *npm update*, but still the changes are not reflected.  The same thing happens if I delete the *dist* folder and rebuild.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Good question.  I have the same problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Were you able to get through ?

Comment: Yes, I eventually did.  I had to delete node_modules and angular, then reinstall both.  But that caused another problem which I finally fixed by downgrading angular to an earlier version.  The newest version was missing some module.  Anyway, I think a better approach would be to delete the dist folder, clear the cache, then do ng build again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Service Worker by any chance? Service Worker will cache everything forcefully and you need to reset it in dev tool.

Comment: I'm new to angular.  Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: I googled it.  Apparently if you delete or rename file called ngsw.json in node_modules/@angular/service-worker, it will disable service worker if its enabled.  I don't have that folder so I guess its disabled.